# NSRegularExpression to detect em-dash in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I currently have the following regex:

```
static inline NSRegularExpression * AuthorRegularExpression() {
    if (!__authorRegularExpression) {
        __authorRegularExpression = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"-\\s*(.)*$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    }

    return __authorRegularExpression;
}
```

As you can see in the pattern it detects a dash (-) followed by some strings.
However now I've changed the format of the dash to an em-dash. So the string looks like the following:

```
  NSString *dashAuthor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C %@", 0x2014, self.theme.quoteAuthor];
```

How do I now change the regex to reflect this, so it can find an author with a trailing em-dash.

Comment: NSLog("%@", dashAuthor); Please....?

Comment: It's just a string. A name.. such as Thomas Jefferson.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match an em dash either with its unicode value (`\u2014`), or by character name, like this: `\N{EM DASH}`.

Comment: So is the pattern now @"\u2014\\s*(.)*$"

Comment: You have to escape the backslash in a string literal, so it would be `@"\\u2014\\s*(.)*$"` (note the second backslash before the `u`).